# why i have an error while runnig the code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

```
>>> & C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe c:/Users/user/Desktop/website_school_2024/practice_classes.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    & C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe c:/Users/user/Desktop/website_school_2024/practice_classes.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

this is the code:

```
print(2)
```

[image]

(i have auto save)

i have an error while running the code.

why??

please help me

Comment: What does this error mean? I don't have an error in the syntax

Comment: The error is because you are in the Python REPL,  not at the command line.   not sure why you had the & at the beginning of the line where you entered the command but you should probably remove that.

Comment: How are you running your code?

Comment: with the tingel in the rigth

Comment: I think you meant the triangle in the upper right corner of the editor window.   The view you are showing in your image seems like it might not be the whole editor window and some stuff is cut off.   The command is correct its just that the command is not running as entered at the command line.  It appears to being executed within the python REPL shell.   if you type: python -i    you will enter the REPL shell with the >>> characters.   if you cut and paste the command starting with the & you will get the same result.

Comment: try typing in that window: exit()

Comment: that will exit out of the repl shell.  then try running it again with the triangle.

Comment: Worked for me when I did exit(). What it means ? Why didn't it work before?

Comment: It didn't work before because the REPL shell is basically the python interpreter in interactive mode.   when you see the >>> that is telling you you are in that shell  REPL stands for Read, Evaluate, Print and Loop.   So whatever you type in there is taken as a Python statement, evalueated and the result printed. Then it asks for next line (Loop).  You were in that and it was telling you the line starting with & was not valid syntax for python code.  It was not taking it as a command line to execute your python module.

Comment: Sorry you got down voted by so many folks,  I wish I could have put in answer for you to accept.